# Json Deserialize to List

Tags: c#, json

I am writing a Windows Phone app that will get a set of data from a server and display each entry in a list box.

The data comes from the server looking like this

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "value1": 777103069782066, 
      "value2": "SomeString", 
      "value3": "TextToDisplay1"
    }, 
    {
      "value1": 750050696652932, 
      "value2": "SomeString2", 
      "value3": "TextToDisplay2"
    }, 
    {
      "value1": 516092242936133, 
      "value2": "SomeString3", 
      "value3": "TextToDisplay3"
    } 
  ]
}
```

I know how to get the data into a dictionary like this

```
Dictionary<string, object> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

But it mashes it all into one dictionary entry (to be expected, that's all there is).

I want to take all of the list items within "data" and store them in a variable - testList - so I can access each individual dictionary from the 'testList'. How can I do this?

Sorry if the question is kind of wordy. I can clarify if needed.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create your own data class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public long value1;
    public string value2;
    public string value3;
}
```

And then deserialize like this:

```
Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<MyClass>> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<MyClass>>>(json);
```

Where `IEnumerable<MyClass>` part will be your `testList`

**UPD**: in case if you want to avoid custom object use something like

```
Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>>> values = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>>>>(json);
```

Comment: Because the data that I am using comes from a server in JSON format. I am trying to avoid having all my data entries hard coded since the server will be changing them in the future. All I am really looking to do is to convert all the items inside my dictionary's key - "data" into a list of dictionaries.